# Delete items from ComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I want to delete items from comboBox on java, if items exist in data table's column.

For example comboBox items: **09:00, 10:00, 11:00** and Data table value: **10:00**  on this example, it must delete **"10:00"** on Combobox.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DefaultComboBoxModel` which has `public void removeElementAt(int index)` method.

Or just recreate the model when necessary and set the new model to already existing combobox.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`removeItemAt(int itemIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItemAt%28int%29) method of `JComboBox`.

Comment: Requires a mutable data model.

Comment: @trashgod true - but that's the default except when explicitly setting a custom immutable model :-)